# SQL Select a row as if it has no space on it

Tags: mysql

```
id | col1      | col2 |
_________________________
 1 | Aceh     | Denpasar
 2 | Aceh     | Banda Aceh
 3 | Sumatera | Asahan
```

I want to select the row with `id` `2` with `WHERE` criteria `BandaAceh` at `col2`

My desired result is

```
   id | col1      | col2 |
   _________________________
    2 | Aceh     | Banda Aceh
```

I know it won't work with simple `SELECT...WHERE` statement as I need to remove the space on the value of col2.

How can i make it possible to get as a result the row with id `2` by just using `BandaAceh` on its `WHERE` statement?

NOTE: I want an exact search, we can't really use `LIKE` as we have a exact value to put on the `WHERE` clause, its just a matter of a space character that we need to eliminate on the criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
 select * from table where replace(col2,' ', '') = 'BandaAceh'
```

Comment: the name must replace to you col name.  to col2